# How to represent a non SQL custom schema structure in a SQL database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have an interesting problem. I have a relational database to which i can use custom scripts to create the tables. It's pseudo SQL and doesn't use standard create syntax. Rather it's fairly limited. What i want to do is store my schema in a MySQL database.

In my custom relational database I have a table called:

`Person` with fields

- `id` as `NUMBER` not nullable PK
- `name` as `TEXT (64)` characters max
- `year of birth` as `DATE`

So in order to generate the create scripts I thought of using MySQL database to store the schema. For example

I have a MySQL table called `custom_table` with `id` and `name`

e.g. `1, Person` would be the first record in it

I have another MySQL table called `custom_fields` with the following:

- `field_id` as int, not null, pk
- `table_name_id`, foreign key to custom_table
- `field_name` as varchar(255)
- `field_type` as varchar(255)
- `is_primary_key` as tinyint(1)
- `is_nullable` as tinyint(1)

The data set would look like:

| field_id | table_name_id | field_name | field_type | is_primary_key | is_nullable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | id | NUMBER | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | name | TEXT | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | year | DATE | 0 | 1 |

The part that I am stuck on, is how/where do i store the length of the `TEXT` field. I have other field types such as decimal which accept additional parameters or default values as well.

I was thinking of maybe have a table called `field_date`, `field_number`, `field_text` which would be related back to the `custom_fields` table via foreign key relationship but i am unsure how to enforce the fact that each `field_id` should only exist at most one time in any other table. Any insight would be appreciated or direction to research. My challenge is that I haven't been able to find anything in stack or other sites related to something like this.

Comment: Can I take a step back and ask _why_ you want to create a structure like this? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Hey, sure thanks. This software I use has a relational database. I have close to 100+ tables which are a pain to create, update, etc manually from GUI. The software support creating and modifying these tables via javascript (but it's not SQL), rather i pass in the field name, type and other parameters. I want to store my schema somewhere and then dynamically generate these table create scripts. The place my schema is stored needs to be maintainable. My thought was database tables could store this schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes database tables can and do store the schema. It's called the '[catalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_catalog)'. Every SQL database should have one, and it's maintained by every `CREATE TABLE`, etc. And you can query it, just like any other table.

If your (rather mysterious) "pseudo SQL" DBMS doesn't do that, get a proper DBMS. Don't try to re-invent the wheel, because trying to maintain a 'shadow' of the actual schema will lead to anomalies.